# How to find application that can handle incoming calls in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

In android if we use resolve intent along with CATEGORY_HOME or CATEGORY_LAUNCHER I will get back all applications which are installed home applications or applications which are launchable respectively.
Similarly is there any **way to find applications which can handle incoming calls** , like normal android phone app, Viber, Skype etc.

Regards
Kozlov

Answer (score 0):

How about adding [ACTION_ANSWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER) action to your Intent?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> results = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

Comment: Hello hopia, I tested with above code "results" is 0, atleast com.android.phone should have been there.